# Is there a way to open an iframe onclick without using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Setting up a UI where the user clicks on an image, and an iframe on top of the image. I'd like to avoid JQuery if at all possible, and use pure JavaScript instead.

Comment: What about this: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: What about standard browser APIs?

Comment: Bluescreened last time I tried it.

Comment: What problem are you having doing this in plain JS? Change the `src` of the `iframe` to the page you want to show, and give it a class whose CSS raises it to the top. When the user dismisses it, remove the class.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit obtuse, but it all you want to do is open an iframe when you click an image, just wrap the image html in an anchor tag with the target being your iframe name. No JS needed.

If that isn't what you want, maybe some more detail would help.